# Trouble having passed GET variable display on target page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm going crazy here. I have two pages. Page A and Page B. I simply want to set a variable in Page A, pass it to Page B via GET method (URL) and then have code display the variable. I do not get any errors, but the the variable simply will not display. Here is the code:

Page A:

```
print "<a href=\"http://mysite.net/page-b?var=".$id ."\">" .$name . "</a><br>";
```

Page B:

```
    <?php       


        //db connect info above not shown
        $password = "*****";
        $usertable = "stories";
        $myfield = (int) $_GET['id'];


        //Connect to db
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");
        mysql_select_db($dbname);

        //Fetch from db
        $query = "SELECT * FROM stories where story_id = $myfield";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        echo "TEXT: "; 
        if ($result) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $name = $row["story_id"];
                echo $name;
            }
      }
  ?>
```

All I get returned is "TEXT:"
But it want it to show "TEXT: 4" (because I know 4 is the story_id from page a. I even see the 4 in the URL of page B being successfully passed, but can't get it to display here.

As a second part of the question, my REAL GOAL is not to simply print the story_id, but rather the story text itself (a paragraph of text). This variable is in the same table called story_text. It seems a pipe dream to get the actual story text to display when I can't even simply have the story_id number print as a test.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

```
$myfield = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

this should be

```
$myfield = (int) $_GET['var'];
```

Answer (score 2):

if your url is 
http://mysite.net/page-b?var=".$id ."\"

The variable passed will be $var, not $id

```
$myfield = (int) $_GET['id'];    // WRONG
$myfield = (int) $_GET['var'];   // RIGHT
```